# IF function in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax

Why this is not working?

```
<?php 
if (count($payment_method) > 0 
    && !(count($payment_method) == 1 
    && implode('',$payment_method) == 'PayPal'));
?>
```

Error is here

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\signup\templates\default\html\subscription.php on line 239

Comment: So `$payment_method` is not an Array or an Object! It has to be one or the other to be countable

Comment: or an object that implements Countable interface

Comment: Use `gettype()` to determine the type of $payment_method. Definitely it is not an array.

Comment: Do a simple `print_r($payment_method);` and show us the output if it does not suddenly become obvious to you what the issue is when you see it

Comment: _IF function in PHP_ `if` is not a function

Comment: `> 0` and `!= 1` is just `> 1`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It means that your `$payment_method` variable has to be an array or an object that looks something like:

```
class MyClass implements Countable {
    public count(): int {}
}
```

You can simply learn what value it has by using the `var_dump($payment_method)` function and keep on.

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition to include a test on array type

```
<?php 
if (is_array($payment_method)
    && count($payment_method) > 0 
    && !(count($payment_method) == 1 && current($payment_method) == 'PayPal')
);
?>
```